# PHP : Parse error, syntax error

Tags: php

`$router->addRoutes('', ['controller'=>'Home', 'action'=>'index']);`

during compilation its generate an error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Please help.

Comment: Your php version is not >=5.4

Comment: Yes ... but how to solve any other code reference ??? @u_mulder

Comment: @ARNAB, Your best bet is to upgrade your PHP version if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If is not >=5.4

PHP versions <= 5.4 do not support the `[]` syntax for array construction. Instead you shoud use `array()`:

```
$router->addRoutes('',array('controller'=>'Home', 'action'=>'index'));
```

Comment: thank you @scaisEdge

Comment: thank you  @ARNAB..  Well if my answer is right please mark as accepeted  too.